# Do I need to know every note I am going to sing?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, voice, melody

If I am learning to sing a song do I need to know what notes and chords are in the song to find my reference pitch for the first note I am going to sing or singing the first note happens unconsciously without thinking about the reference pitch?

Comment: When you sing for yourself it probably doesn‘t matter much. // When at least one other instrument is involved, it does matter: you should all follow the same key. // You probably can do without stating „this pitch is Eb“, but you should be able to reproduce exactly that pitch. // What‘s the reason for your question?

Answer (score 8):

It *may* happen unconsciously, and having absolute pitch would make it happen regardless.

However, it's not guaranteed. I remember playing in a band where one number started with just the singer, no reference. I pointed out that he'd need at least a chord or note, and that sounded naff. He said it didn't matter, he'd sung the song thousands of times. We argued, and to end the fuss, I said 'o.k., we'll try once more (in rehearsal), and if you hit it, that's the end of the matter.'

The song was in key E, and while I said that, I noodled in key E♭. He started singing, and when the rest of the band did come in, he was out of tune! He couldn't understand why, and it was never explained to him. But he made sure that the song sung previously was in the same key from then on. Lesson learned - most of us need a guide note/chord.

Comment: The [Levitin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levitin_effect) is likely a manifestation of that "*may* happen unconsciously".

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have *absolute pitch*, you need to have some way to know the first note. If the song starts with an instrumental introduction, you may deduce the first note from that. Otherwise, you need to hear some reference note before, e.g. by playing a note on an instrument.

In choirs, it is the conductor's role to give the starting pitch. See e.g. this recording:

The conductor starts by placing a tuning fork close to his ear, to find the starting pitch himself, then sings a proper pitch to the choir (we can't hear it over the applause), and only then the singers starts to sing. The singers whose lines enter later deduce their pitches from the notes sung by the singers who started to sing before them.

Comment: I've definitely seen choirs of people (who probably didn't all have perfect pitch) start singing, on the correct notes, from silence. No reference note involved. I think there's more to it than what's said in this answer - doesn't *practice* come into it?

Comment: @AakashM - I recall being able to sight-sing with pretty much 100% accuracy in Grade 7 (in school choir), one year before figuring out I had absolute/perfect pitch in Grade 8 (could recognize only Middle C back then, but it counted!). Maybe something similar to that - besides the [Levitin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levitin_effect) - is going on.

Comment: @AakashM I don't know what exactly you saw, but there are several possibilities: 1. they heard and memorized the note before entering the stage, 2. the starting note was given to them very discreetly (note, how swiftly it occurs in the video I posted!), or maybe via headphones? 3. if this wasn't the first piece, they simply deduced the relation from the previous song?

Comment: Practice and discipline of course helps, because it allows you to memorize pitch for a longer time without drifting away.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I don't have perfect pitch, but I'm not certain if perfect pitch is precise and reliable within several cents (which is what you need to be in tune) for everyone? And as Tim's anecdote demonstrates, the Levitin effect can be very unreliable.

Comment: But then it also all comes to how professional the choir is, and how much do they strive for perfection. Sometimes a spontaneous performance, even if it's not exactly in the planned key, can carry the exact emotions that are needed.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - an interesting phenomenon. I can only guess that AakashM's choir either did what user1079505 suggested, or there were enough strong singers amongst them to carry the others into the right key. Interested to find out if it was acapella, in which case it's a slightly different scenario.

Comment: @AakashM - My absolute pitch for singing notes is accurate to within a few cents. Quite possibly helping is my memories of a lot of music I've ever heard, down to the instrumentation.

Comment: I think you don't need necessarily perfect pitch for start singing a right note from nothing. If you've done it thousand of times before with a reference  you start to memorizing  the tension and feeling of your muscles and cords.

Comment: @flappix - Actually, I don't tend to memorize muscle/vocal cord tension and/or feeling at all. I just match the note I sing to the note in my head.

Comment: @flappix - it's doubtful any of us do that. It's just an innate 'feeling' when we start the song. Which may, or may not be correct (as my example). From complete silence things are probably no better. Unless, as Dekkadeci, one has absolute pitch, when things are very different.